# How to only add positive numeric string to list

Tags: python, python-3.x

How to only add positive numeric string to list

```
lst = '3 -1 0 2 4 2 4 79'
arr = list(map(lambda x: int(x) if int(x) > 0 else None, lst.split()))
print(arr)
```

this is the answer i get:

```
[3, None, None, 2, 4, 2, 4, 79]
```

but i want:

```
[3, 2, 4, 2, 4, 79]
```

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter

Comment: You want to *filter* not *map*. But idiomatically, you'd just use a list comprehension (which is for expressing mapping/filtering operations)

Answer (score 1):

```
lst = '3 -1 0 2 4 2 4 79'    
numbers = [int(i) for i in lst.split(' ') if int(i) > 0]
```

Or you can filter out the None values:

```
lst = '3 -1 0 2 4 2 4 79'  
arr = list(filter(None, map(lambda x: int(x) if int(x) > 0 else None, lst.split())))
```

Answer (score 1):

Using filter and map:

```
lst = '3 -1 0 2 4 2 4 79'

print(list(filter(lambda x: x > 0, map(int, lst.split()))))
```

**Output:**

```
[3, 2, 4, 2, 4, 79]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also filter with the string isdecimald method to avoid non-numeric values and keep only numbers that do not have symbols

```
lst = '3 -1 0 2 4 2 4 79'
arr = list(filter(lambda x: x.isdecimal() and int(x) > 0, lst.split()))
print(arr)
```

**output**

```
['3', '2', '4', '2', '4', '79']
```